# HTTP Status 500 error in Openbravo ERP 3

Tags: java, erp, openbravo

Some days back I installed Openbravo ERP 3 and it was working fine. I had installed two modules:
i. Loyalty Management 1.6.0
ii. POS Synchronization WebService 1.2.5

Today I uninstalled the above modules and did a rebuild. After that I restarted the Openbravo Appliance through VMware player.
After restarting Openbravo ERP is giving "HTTP Status 500 -" error.

The entire error is as follows:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: Exception thrown Exception thrown Truncated class file
    org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:63)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter.doFilter(DalRequestFilter.java:103)
root cause

org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: Exception thrown Truncated class file
    org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:56)
    org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelFilter.doFilter(KernelFilter.java:71)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter$1.doAction(DalRequestFilter.java:81)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:46)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter.doFilter(DalRequestFilter.java:103)
root cause

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.openbravo.utils.SessionExpirationFilter.doFilter(SessionExpirationFilter.java:66)
    org.openbravo.utils.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:35)
    org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelFilter$1.doAction(KernelFilter.java:62)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:46)
    org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelFilter.doFilter(KernelFilter.java:71)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter$1.doAction(DalRequestFilter.java:81)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.ThreadHandler.run(ThreadHandler.java:46)
    org.openbravo.dal.core.DalRequestFilter.doFilter(DalRequestFilter.java:103)
```

Java version which can with Openbravo ERP 3 is "1.6.0_32".
Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the below commands one after another:

1. ant compile.complete
2. ant smartbuild

Hope this solves your problem..

Comment: Thanks alot was stuck here for so long.